# Disable select options based on another select along with db data

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select

I have a conference registration where users can choose to register for workshops on 2 days. They cannot choose the same workshop for the second day. However, each workshop has a soft-limit of 40 participants so when the registration loads, there's a query to get which workshops have seats left.

Code below:

```
<select name="workshop1" required="required" id="workshop1">
    <option disabled selected value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value=”wkshp1”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp2”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp3”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp4”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp5”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp6”>Workshop name</option>
</select>
<select name="workshop1" required="required" id="workshop2">
    <option disabled selected value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value=”wkshp1”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp2”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp3”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp4”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp5”>Workshop name</option>
    <option value=”wkshp6”>Workshop name</option>
</select>
```

I'm using this code from Stack-overflow which works perfectly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#workshop1").change(function() {
        $("select[name=workshop2] option").removeAttr("disabled");
        var workshopName = $("select[name=workshop1]").val();
        $("select[name=workshop2] option[value=" + workshopName + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
```

However, while I can disable on page load workshops that are full, the jquery code above will re-enable my disabled options (workshop is full) in workshop2. How do I iterate through all the options and exclude those that are full from being enabled back. The workshops are identical on day 1 & day 2.

Comment: `$("select[name=workshop2] option").removeAttr("disabled");` re-enables all the options. Why do you need this code line?

Comment: The reason for this is if I chose workshop2 for Day 1 so for Day 2 workshop 1 is disabled. But then before I complete the registration, I change my mind and select workshop3. Anyway, I think I have the solution already. Testing it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok manage to solve this by doing the following.
Because full workshops were output with blank values ie. , the script could check this. I added a check for workshop two in the event the user chose workshop1 for day1 then workshop2 for day2 is able to change day1 to workshop1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#workshop1").change(function(){
            $("#workshop2 option").each(function(){
                if ($(this)["0"].value) {
                    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });             
            $("select[name=workshop2] option[value=" + $("select[name=workshop1]").val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
        $("#workshop2").change(function(){
            $("#workshop1 option").each(function(){
                if ($(this)["0"].value) {
                    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });     
            $("select[name=workshop1] option[value=" + $("select[name=workshop2]").val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }); 
    });
```